# for...of - JavaScript keyword Internet Explorer work-around

Tags: javascript, performance, cross-browser, compatibility, ecmascript-6

I am using “for...of” in many places in my Javascript code which is a new technology, part of Javascript’s new specification (ECMAScript 2015 (E56) standard). "for...of" is supported in Chrome, Safari and Firefox. Though, IE doesn’t yet support this new feature ([See this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)). What would be my best approach to support these 4 main browsers - do I revert to "for in/for loop" or do I use browser-sniffing code or is there a better hack to be able to both use some hybrid "for...of" and "for...in"? This is not a repeat of this question here: [link_here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384494/how-well-is-the-for-of-javascript-statement-supported) because I am aware that IE does not support "for...of". What I am looking for is if there is a hack to still use it and still support all the 4 browsers I listed?

Comment: It's ES6, not E56 :)

Comment: You can't polyfill new syntax so the only option to support IE is to use regular for loops.

Comment: You should consider using an ES6 to ES5 compiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the [Traceur](https://google.github.io/traceur-compiler) compiler:

```html
<script src="https://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/bin/traceur.js"></script>
<script src="https://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/src/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="module">
for(var n of ['foo', 'bar'])
  alert(n);
</script>
```

It should work even on IE9.

Answer (score 0):

If you want back compat support for "for...of" your only choice is a compiler (transpiler). If you look here: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ the well known compilers, and the level of support they provide, are well documented.